# Error: The newtxmath and tensor packages with subscriptcorrection

Tags: newtxmath, tensor

Compiling the following Minimal Broken Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
%\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{tensor}
\begin{document}
Consider the following:
\[
A_f = R\indices{_\mu^{\sigma\nu}}
\]
\end{document}
```

leads to the following error messages:

```
! Package tensor Error: Sub/Superscript items out of order on input line 9, 
(tensor)                some index tokens may now have been lost.

See the tensor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 A_f = R\indices{_\mu^{\sigma\nu}}

?
```

However, the code compiles perfectly fine if

- one uses `\usepackage{newtxmath}`, i.e., without `subscriptcorrection`; OR
- one uses `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`; OR
- one uses `\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}`.

What is going on here? Is there a fix to this problem?

**Added**: I have noticed that both `newtxmath` and `mtpro2` implement `subscriptcorrection` by making the underscore `_` active (although it is more likely that `newtxmath` is inspired by `mtpro2`).

---

P.S. The working output if one uses `\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}`:

[image: MWE with mtpro2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tensor` package uses a chain of `\ifx` comparisons to work out what type of index has been given. That works of course if the catcode of `_` (and `^`) when `tensor` is loaded is the same as when `\indices` is used. However, here the catcode of `_` in the preamble is different from the document body: when using  math-active `_`, it's catcode is set to 12 rather than 8. The easiest work-around is to load `tensor` with the correct catcode applied:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
\catcode`\_=12 %
\usepackage{tensor}
\catcode`\_=8 %
\begin{document}
Consider the following:
\[
A_f = R\indices{_\mu^{\sigma\nu}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Presumably the `mtpro2` package sets the catcode of `_` immediately: the `newtxmath` package delays until the start of the document.

A slightly fancier version which automates whether to set the catcode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}
\makeatletter
\edef\savedcodes{\catcode`\noexpand\_=\the\catcode`\_}
\edef\@tempa{\csname opt@newtxmath.sty\endcsname}
\def\@tempb{{subscriptcorrection}}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \in@\expandafter\@tempb\expandafter{\@tempa}
\ifin@
  \catcode`\_=12 %
\fi
\makeatother
\usepackage{tensor}
\savedcodes
\begin{document}
Consider the following:
\[
A_f = R\indices{_\mu^{\sigma\nu}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If `tensor` used a set of `\if` tests, it would work in a catcode-agnostic way. Arguably it should as really the _character_ is important here, not how TeX is interpreting it.

Comment: Wow! I am floored by your updated answer. One quick final question before I accept your answer: Why is there a `<space>` behind each of the assignments ``\catcode`\_=8 %`` (once) and ``\catcode`\_=12 %`` (twice). Shouldn’t they be just ``\catcode`\_=8%`` and ``\catcode`\_=12%`` since this is no LaTeX3 syntax?

Comment: @RuixiZhang No: TeX is looking for an optional space to terminate the number. I've deliberately given it one: best-practice.

Comment: Thanks! And you are right about `mtpro2`’s approach. A simple test ``\typeout{\the\catcode`\_}`` shows that `_` changes to `8` or `12` immediately after `mtpro2` with `nosubcorr` and `subcorr`, respectively. But `_` remains `8` after `newtxmath` no matter `nosubcorr` or `subcorr`, and changes to `12` if `subcorr` due to `\AtBeginDocument`. Your solution works with any of these four situations.